# Why do I receive an evaluation error when I call this previously defined variable using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am new to R and working on a small project:

Repex:

## I have a dataset called filterdascom4 which has the variables as below

```
> head(filterdacsom4)
  Year       Zip Total_Population Median_Income      City State
1 2017 ZCTA5 00601            17599         11757  Adjuntas    PR
2 2017 ZCTA5 00602            39209         16190    Aguada    PR
3 2017 ZCTA5 00603            50135         16645 Aguadilla    PR
4 2017 ZCTA5 00606             6304         13387   Maricao    PR
5 2017 ZCTA5 00610            27590         18741    Anasco    PR
6 2017 ZCTA5 00612            62566         17744   Arecibo    PR
```

I am trying to use dplyr and tidyverse to mutate and create a new column for population to income ratio and then find which zip code had the highest population to income ratio in 2017

My input:

```
demograph_ratio <-  filterdacsom4 %>% dplyr::filter(Year %in% c(2017)) %>% 
  spread(Year,Median_Income) %>% group_by(Zip) %>%
  mutate(Poptoincomeratio = Total_Population/Median_Income)
demograph_ratio
```

However, when I run the above I receive an error saying:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'Median_Income' not found.
```

Which is strange because when I try to debug it:

```
filterdacsom4$Median_Income
```

It does display the correct Output:

```
[1]  11757  16190  16645  13387  18741  17744  14918  17157  16727  16401
  [11]  16832  17579   9632  15736  14448  16292  29160  13071  16095  20564
  [21]  12236  14966  17770  19674  16771  15401  13843  12996  14456  18032
  [31]  13416  18333  15730  14500  15315  15043  14128  18739  15918  18491
  [41]  18076  18971  14375  14487  16532  13960  18207  17489  15820  12440
```

Why am I receiving this error and is there a better way to code this in order to find the population to income ratio as per zipcode

Comment: You seem to be missing a column name in your example. There's probably an error in your data input that you didn't recognize.

Comment: If you data is same what you show to us , change filter(Year %in% c('2017 ZCTA5'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put in a dummy column name for the missing column between Year and Zip, and I could see no reason for a spread operation so took that out and everything seemed to "work":

```
demograph_ratio <-  filterdacsom4 %>% filter(Year %in% c(2017)) %>% 
      group_by(Zip) %>%
     mutate(Poptoincomeratio = Total_Population/Median_Income)

> demograph_ratio
# A tibble: 6 x 8
# Groups:   Zip [6]
   Year code    Zip Total_Population Median_Income City      State Poptoincomeratio
  <int> <fct> <int>            <int>         <int> <fct>     <fct>            <dbl>
1  2017 ZCTA5   601            17599         11757 Adjuntas  PR               1.50 
2  2017 ZCTA5   602            39209         16190 Aguada    PR               2.42 
3  2017 ZCTA5   603            50135         16645 Aguadilla PR               3.01 
4  2017 ZCTA5   606             6304         13387 Maricao   PR               0.471
5  2017 ZCTA5   610            27590         18741 Anasco    PR               1.47 
6  2017 ZCTA5   612            62566         17744 Arecibo   PR               3.53
```

If you wanted to see why there was no Year or Median_Income column after the `spread` operation look at the "intermediate result" that got passed on to `mutate`

```
not_ratio <-  filterdacsom4 %>% filter(Year %in% c(2017)) %>% 
     spread(Year,Median_Income) 

> not_ratio
   code Zip Total_Population      City State  2017
1 ZCTA5 601            17599  Adjuntas    PR 11757
2 ZCTA5 602            39209    Aguada    PR 16190
3 ZCTA5 603            50135 Aguadilla    PR 16645
4 ZCTA5 606             6304   Maricao    PR 13387
5 ZCTA5 610            27590    Anasco    PR 18741
6 ZCTA5 612            62566   Arecibo    PR 17744
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have also written code to find the maximum poptoincome ratio max(sapply(demograph_ratio$Poptoincomeratio, max). Pardon me this is a rookie question but how can I find the correlated zip code of this highest poptoincomeratio which is 4.454182

Comment: Not sure: Possibly `demograph_ratio[ which(demograph_ratio$Poptoincomeratio == 4.454182) , "Zip" ]` although using `==` is prone to inexactness when dealing with floating point values and might be better to use `all.equal` or perhaps use "==" to compare to the `max` of that column

Answer (score 0):

It seems that having two parameters in `spread`, the column name of `Median_Income` changes to the `year` value:

```
demograph_ratio <-  filterdacsom4 %>% dplyr::filter(Year %in% c(2017)) %>% 
  spread(Year,Median_Income) %>% group_by(Zip)
demograph_ratio

  Zip         Total_Population City      State `2017`
  <chr>                  <dbl> <chr>     <chr>  <dbl>
1 ZCTA5 00601            17599 Adjuntas  PR     11757
2 ZCTA5 00602            39209 Aguada    PR     16190
3 ZCTA5 00603            50135 Aguadilla PR     16645
4 ZCTA5 00606             6304 Maricao   PR     13387
5 ZCTA5 00610            27590 Anasco    PR     18741
6 ZCTA5 00612            62566 Arecibo   PR     17744
```

Since 42 already showed the answer without the spread operation, I leave that out here

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have also written code to find the maximum poptoincome ratio max(sapply(demograph_ratio$Poptoincomeratio, max). Pardon me this is a rookie question but how can I find the correlated zip code of this highest poptoincomeratio which is 4.454182